# Godot. Specular Highlights in Spatial Material. How?

Tags: unity-game-engine, godot

There is Specular Highlights option in Unity materials. How to achieve the same effect in Godot? I cannot find the appropriate option.
Trying to re-create Unity material in Godot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Specular property you can adjust in SpatialMaterial (in the Metallic section). It works in a way similar to Unreal's specular property. Note that it's a single scalar value, not a color. Keep in mind Godot uses a roughness-metallic PBR workflow.

If you want the specular reflection to have a different color than white (for non-metallic materials) or the albedo's color (for metallic materials), you'll have to write a custom shader and use it in a ShaderMaterial.